# Disable first 7 week from date time new and disable weekends of datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, datepicker

I managed not to disable the first 7 days, I now want to disable weekends (Saturday , Sunday), how can I include it in the `datepicker` function?

Thank you. Here is the code snippets:

```js
$.extend( $.fn.datepicker.defaults, {format: 'dd-mm-yyyy', language: 'de'} );
$('#launchdate').datepicker({ 
    startDate: '+7d'
});
      
 //  beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends ?
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.de.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" />

<input type="text" class="form-control" name="launchdate" id="launchdate" placeholder="Date*" required data-error="Wrong Date!">
```

**Expected Result**: From `date.now()` the next 7 days are disabled, as well as the weekend to be disabled.

Comment: Plz elaborate clearly what your query and the expected results you want? thanks

Comment: Hi @merci, can you specify that you are using datepicker or datetimepicker? These 2 are different.

Comment: @YongShun Hi, i am sorry, i use datepicker Boostrap

Comment: Solution: I found a solution, I added to the html input feld data-date-days-of-week-disabled = "0.6"

Comment: Please write an answer instead of writing it in the question...